# Project compiles successfully, but I get exception about missing drawable

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-studio, android-holo-everywhere

I had my project running in Eclipse, I tried converting it to Android Studio. However, I also downloaded (via github) the latest HoloEverywhere library, and updated contrib/ with ActionBarSherlock library ( I use them both ).

Everything compiles successfully, but when starting the first activity, I get the following exceptions:

```
06-18 10:57:22.611    2190-2190/com.wasp.androidbg             E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wasp.androidbg/com.wasp.androidbg.StartScreen}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_holo_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02013f
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/list_selector_holo_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02013f
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.DrawableCompat.loadDrawable(DrawableCompat.java:138)
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.DrawableCompat.getDrawable(DrawableCompat.java:107)
    at org.holoeverywhere.widget.ListView.setSelector(ListView.java:964)
    at com.wasp.androidbg.StartScreen.onCreate(StartScreen.java:76)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    ... 11 more
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1c/d=0x0 a=2 r=0x7f090011}
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.DrawableCompat.loadDrawable(DrawableCompat.java:128)
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.DrawableCompat.getDrawable(DrawableCompat.java:107)
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:194)
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.DrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(DrawableCompat.java:87)
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.DrawableCompat.createFromXml(DrawableCompat.java:63)
    at org.holoeverywhere.drawable.DrawableCompat.loadDrawable(DrawableCompat.java:135)
    ... 17 more
    06-18 11:04:20.118    2257-2257/com.wasp.androidbg             D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
    06-18 11:04:20.347    2257-2257/com.wasp.androidbg             E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

I don't have any custom themes (yet). I double checked the .apk file, and the file exists, but is named **abs__list_selector_holo_light.xml** - it does have prefix abs__.

I searched but there are no configurations in HoloEverywhere, which use this prefix, or any way to configure it.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: cant help without any trace of code :)

Comment: I don't have any code to show, as I don't use anything HoloEverywhere specific yet. However, I have another project which works with both, so I'm investigating what could be the problem ...